# dateTime to short format in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to display date time like  **01/08/11** , but i write this

```
string title_row = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

and the result is **8/1/2011** how i can change the formt to  **01/08/11**

Comment: Do you mean without having to change your PC's region?

Comment: `.ToString("dd/MM/yy")` should do it for you

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I doubt that the OP wants *minutes* between the days and years...

Comment: @Jon Sorry disastrous typo in case of `DateTime`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Thanks for editing. I only mentioned it as I've seen it be the cause of various problems on here before :)

Comment: Thanks everyone it works with DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"). As you have shown me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

, alternatively you should investigate [`Culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx).

Comment: Aah .. same typo as i did in the comments ! Please check `mm`

Comment: true, I read the comment after your correction, changed my answer while I checked, now I've corrected. I could blame my flimsy self confidence but I'll go for willingness to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string format parameter of the [ToString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to achieve any format you like, like this:

```
string title_row = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
//01/08/11
```

Answer (score 1):

For example using DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy)

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");` should get you the required format

ToShortDateString() is governed by the culture settings and the display format is derived from the current culture, so to get it in the desired format pass in the appropriate formatting.